# Can someone hack or misuse UID of a user in Firestore openly listed in a doc

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, uid

(My app requires **authentication**),
=>  I am making a collection *THINGS* and users from the collection *USER* can write doc to it.

- When they write to it, the doc id is automatically generated but in
  order to query the doc, i am adding a field in it called
  *uploaders_UID*, which will have the *UID* of the uploader ( so he will be able to find his uploads).
- Now there is another class of users *PROUSERS* (also
  **authenticated** )which don't need to know the *UID* to see the documents in the collection *THINGS*.
- So my question is those users in *PROUSERS* who dont require the
  *UID* still gets a snapshot which has the *UID*  and its easy for someone to extract the *UID* i guess.

  1. What are the consequences of doing such a thing and is it dangerous,
     can i do it?
  2. what all things a *PROUSER* could do with the *UID* of another user
     (saying the collection THINGS is only writable by *USERS* if they
     are **authenticated** ),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood of your app's flow, the PROUSER will only be able to read all uploads but not edit/delete documents that were not created by himself.

If that is the case, there is no real problem of PROUSERS having access to uids, as long as you set some sort of control on what a user is **authorized** to do or not with your firestore's firebase rules, you can find more details on how to do it in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) and on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=7&t=0s).

Another thing that you could do is "Cloak" the document that you obtain from the database by assigning its field's values to a JSON object leaving the uid out of it.

Comment: Yes PROUSER will only be able to read the docs and that rule will be set in the Firebase rules tab, i don't want to cloak the UID as the PROUSER will need it to query all the docs of the USER in another case, is that okay to do ? thanks your your answer !

Comment: Everything lies on the Firebase Rules, if they are set with proper authorization there is no problem with that.